# how to add new row dynamically in reactable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add new row onclick of accordion i.e while expand using [reactable](https://glittershark.github.io/reactable/), attached the expected result.
I have showed the table structured data using **Tr** and **Td** from reactable but however, not sure to add the new row.
onclick of the arrow the dynamic row should expand,I tried to do so but wasn't able to achieve that.

```
class PolicyDetails extends Component {
  showPolicyOperation = (e,models) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const {callbacks} = this.props
    const activeClass = document.querySelectorAll('.fa-angle-up')
    const currentTarget = e.currentTarget;
    if(currentTarget.classList.contains('fa-angle-up')){
      currentTarget.classList.remove('fa-angle-up');
      currentTarget.classList.add('fa-angle-down');
    }else{
      currentTarget.classList.remove('fa-angle-down');
      currentTarget.classList.add('fa-angle-up');
    }
    activeClass && activeClass.forEach(node => {
      node.classList.remove('fa-angle-up');
      node.classList.add('fa-angle-down');
    })
    callbacks.fetchPoliciesWithId(models.id)
  }

  getHeaders = () => {
    let headers = ([
      <Th key="0" column=""></Th>,
      <Th key="1" column="id">Policy Id</Th>,
      <Th key="2" column="serviceType">Service</Th>,
      <Th key="3" column="name">Policy Name</Th>,
      <Th key="4" column="description">Policy Description</Th>,
      <Th key="5" column="policyLabel">Policy Label</Th>,
      <Th key="6" column="policyType">Policy Type</Th>,
      <Th key="7" column="operation">Operation</Th>,
      <Th key="8" column="action">Actions</Th>
    ])
    return headers;
  }

  pageChange = (page) => {
    this.cPoliciesData.params.page = page - 1 || undefined;
    this.props.callbacks.fetchPolicies();
  }

  getRows = (models, idx) => {
    const state = this.props.options._vState
    let rows = ([
      <Td key="0" column="">
        <i className="fa pointer fa-angle-down"
          aria-hidden="true" key = {idx} onClick={e => {
            state.isPolicySelected = !state.isPolicySelected;
            this.showPolicyOperation(e,models)
          }}></i></Td>,
      <Td key="1" column="id">{<a>{models.id}</a>}</Td>,
      <Td key="2" column="serviceType">{models.serviceType || "--"}</Td>,
      <Td key="3" column="name">{models.name || "--"}</Td>,
      <Td key="4" column="description">{models.description || "--"}</Td>,
      <Td key="5" column="policyLabel">{"--"}</Td>,
      <Td key="6" column="policyType">{models.serviceType == 'tag' && models.policyType == 0 ? "Tag Based" : POLICY_TYPE[models.policyType].label}</Td>,
      <Td key="7" column="operation">{"--"}</Td>,
      <Td key="8" column="action">{"--"}</Td>,
    ]);
    let operation = state.isPolicySelected && <Tr className="special-row">
            <Th column="name">
              <strong className="name-header">First Name, Last Name</strong>
            </Th>
            <Th column="age">
              <em className="age-header">Age, years</em>
            </Th>
          </Tr>
    rows.push(operation)
    return rows;
  }

  render() {
    const {options , callbacks} = this.props;
    const {cPoliciesData, _vState} = options
    
    return (
      <Row className="m-t-md">
        {/* <Col md={12}> */}
        <PanelBody>
          <Table data={cPoliciesData}
            tableAttr={{ className: "table table-hover" }}
            getHeaders={this.getHeaders}
            getRowData={this.getRows}
            pagination={true}
            pageChange={this.pageChange}
          >

          </Table>

        </PanelBody>
        {/* </Col> */}
      </Row>
    )
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add in array . and then with
UseEffect(()=>{
},[options._vState])